# How to open file .ftl into of war file

Tags: java, spring, templates, jboss, war

I try to open an ftl file from my war file

```
// Load Template
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");
```

The template The template is in the path java / main / resources / template.ftl

But when i try to access from class to template.ftl file, sends me the following error:

```
18:47:55,255 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1) java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template src/main/resources/template.ftl not found.
18:47:55,263 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:489)
18:47:55,270 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:452)
18:47:55,289 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
18:47:55,292 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
18:47:55,295 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:47:55,303 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
18:47:55,306 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
18:47:55,309 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(
18:47:55,312 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
18:47:55,315 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
18:47:55,319 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
18:47:55,322 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(
18:47:55,326 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(
18:47:55,329 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
18:47:55,332 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
18:47:55,336 ERROR [stderr] (pool-4-thread-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I print the absolute path, take the jboss server.

Anyone know how to open this type of files from a war.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is located your file in the war?  Are you getting the file in this way Template template = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl"); ? or are you using a different path ?

Comment: The ftl file is located in the src / main / resources path. When I enter the Template template = cfg.getTemplate ("template.ftl") path, I sends me an error     Template src/main/resources/template.ftl not found.   The problem is that the server takes the absolute path, that is, it looks for the file in the JBOSS installation BIN folder and not in the deployments folder

Comment: I think the file is not located in src/main/resources, in your maven project the file is located in that path but when you generate your war it is located in a different location. What is that location ?

Comment: When I deploy the war, the file path is in the WEB-INF / classes / template.ftl folder, but the problem is that it does not matter if I give it that route, the server always takes the absolute path and points to bin folder of the JBOSS server

Comment: You can use WebappTemplateLoader templateLoader = new WebappTemplateLoader(servletContext, "WEB-INF/templates");
templateLoader.setURLConnectionUsesCaches(false);
templateLoader.setAttemptFileAccess(false);
cfg.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader);

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it that way.